# How to update JSON response through JavaScript and return the modified JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular10

I need your inputs in writing the JavaScript function which takes the JSON response data from the REST API call and updates the response by removing certain elements based on condition. I have attached a sample of my JSON file.

```
 {
  "formId": "TEST1",
  "name": "parent-Rally",
  "processDefinitionId": "parent-Rally:242:431719",
  "formDefinition": {
    "id": "523ae7c2",
    "name": "Rally",
    "key": "Rally",
    "version": 244,
    "fields": [
      {
        "fieldType": null,
        "id": "dateofincident",
        "name": "Date of incident",
        "type": "date",
        "value": null,
        "required": true,
        "readOnly": false,
        "overrideId": false,
        "placeholder": null,
        "layout": null,
        "sizeX": 0,
        "sizeY": 0,
        "fieldGroupId": "5,3",
        "selectedDropDown": null,
        "bootStrapWidth": {
          "widthClass": "col-sm-6 col-md-6",
          "label": "50%"
        },
        "defaultOption": null,
        "referenceName": null,
        "fieldGroup": [
          {
            "id": 5,
            "label": "Controls_Edit",
            "fieldId": null
          },
          {
            "id": 3,
            "label": "Controls_ReadOnly",
            "fieldId": null
          }
        ],
        "groupName": "Controls_Edit,Controls_ReadOnly",
        "dropDownList": null,
        "key": null,
        "dataType": null,
        "sequence": 1,
        "helpText": null,
        "fieldId": null,
        "updatedTime": null,
        "updatedUserId": null,
        "fieldValue": null,
        "statusAutoComplete": false,
        "fileUploadList": []
      },
      {
        "fieldType": null,
        "id": "incidentriskrating",
        "name": "Incident Risk Rating",
        "type": "dropdown",
        "value": null,
        "required": false,
        "readOnly": false,
        "overrideId": false,
        "placeholder": null,
        "layout": null,
        "sizeX": 0,
        "sizeY": 0,
        "fieldGroupId": "5,3",
        "selectedDropDown": {
          "id": 15,
          "label": "Incident Risk Rating",
          "fieldId": null
        },
        "bootStrapWidth": {
          "widthClass": "col-sm-6 col-md-6",
          "label": "50%"
        },
        "defaultOption": null,
        "referenceName": null,
        "fieldGroup": [
          {
            "id": 5,
            "label": "Controls_Edit",
            "fieldId": null
          },
          {
            "id": 3,
            "label": "Controls_ReadOnly",
            "fieldId": null
          }
        ],
        "groupName": "Controls_Edit,Controls_ReadOnly",
        "dropDownList": null,
        "key": null,
        "dataType": null,
        "sequence": 2,
        "helpText": "Level 1- Further Escalation (emergency response)\nLevel 2- Escalation of the Situation (non-emergency, however warranted threat)\nLevel 3- Early Warning Signs  (no immediate threat. No further investigation needed at this time)\n",
        "fieldId": null,
        "updatedTime": null,
        "updatedUserId": null,
        "fieldValue": null,
        "statusAutoComplete": false,
        "fileUploadList": []
      }
    ],
    "outcomes": []
  }
}
```

In the above JSON file, I have to delete the complete element when their attribute 'required' under the fields is set to true. Can anyone help me with this. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

first you do a JSON.parse command,

```
var data = JSON.parse(yourjson);
```

and after this command, you have a new object data, with lot of keys,

```
data.formmID, data.name,... and so on
```

so you can modify your object following your condition and finally, you do a stringify command to recreate your jsonfile:

```
var jsondata = JSON.stringify(data);
```